# Gradle duplicate entry error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Im getting the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper$Callback.class

with these dependencies in my gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

I also have muldiDexEnable set to true.

Here are libs

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything in your `libs/` directory? Also, change `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0` to `com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1`, so all of your support library versions match.

Comment: I just added screenshot of libs

Comment: It is due to support library mismatch

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. In your module's `libs/` directory, do you have any JAR files?

Comment: Oh sorry, no i don't. Changing the com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 to com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 fixed the issue for me though. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **same version** of the support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```